# error: ("maybe you meant to use '->'?)

Tags: c++, syntax-error

i have a problem with a fuction in  a class:

```
     struct  game{
        string cods;
        string n;
        string g;
        int v;
        game *p;
     };

     class list2 {
         private:
             game *pr;
             game *a;

         public:
          list2() {
              pr=a=NULL;
           }

     string& Acccods (game *p){     // I GOT THE ERROR IN THIS FUCTION.
         return *p.cods;
     }  
      };
```

It fail to compile and i don't know why. i "wasted" hours and hours trying to fix it.

Comment: Use either `(*p).cods` or `p->cods`.  The latter is preferred, which the compiler even suggested to you.

Comment: Yup that is the answer

Comment: This is not C#. Please be more careful with your tags for future questions.

Comment: Yes ty, i didn't know how the "->" works, so  i was no idea what to do, but thanks! , now i know!.

Its c++ PoweredByOrange ,sorry for the c# in the tag.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem stems from the operator precedence of the `*` vs `.` operator. `.` takes precedence, so you end up trying to use the `.` operator on a pointer, which is invalid. Instead, use `p->cods`.

Comment: thanks! , now i understand , i was a fool for wasting so much time in a syntax-error like this, thanks again.